# How to handle a Tensorflow session in a multiprocessing environment with fork()?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, fork

I am working on a C++ application running Tensorflow. The app has to run well with `fork()` as the code bellow. However, I have learned that [Tensorflow runtime is not fork-safe](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448#issuecomment-258934405). The code hangs when it reaches to the `Session.run()` command. As I am a beginner in C++, I would like to ask you for suggestion how should I run Tensorflow in this case.

Edit: The object is created in the main thread and `fork()` may be called many times.

```
int main ()
{
  Myapp myapp("path_to_model");
  switch(fork()) {
    case 0: {/* Child */
        myapp.get_embedding(some_data);
        break;
    }
    case -1:{ /* Error */
        cerr << "Problem forking" << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
        cout << "on the parent process";
        break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

myapp:

```
//#ifndef _MYAPP_H_
//#define _MYAPP_H_
#ifndef MYAPP_H_
#define MYAPP_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

class Myapp {
    string protobuf_fn; // model filename
    public:
        Session *sess;
        /*constructor with model file name*/
        Myapp (string pb_fn){
            //init the session and load the graph
          TF_CHECK_OK(loadModelpb(pb_fn));
        }
        /*read trained model file into the session*/
        tensorflow::Status loadModelpb(string pb_fn);

        /* get an embedding by running Session.run()
         * For now, it hangs when gets called on a child process.
         */
        Tensor get_embedding(Data some_data) const;

};

#endif /*_MYAPP_H_*/
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but names beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like for example `_MYAPP_H_`) are reserved for the compiler and standard library implementations. Do not define such symbols or names yourself. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thank you.

Comment: If you fork first and then initialise Tensorfllow, you should be Ok.

Comment: @n.m. That sounds reasonable but it may fork many times and the object is created in the main process. I'll add this to the question.